# MySQL clusters - sync a table

Tags: mysql, clustering, ndbcluster

I've been developing a software that runs on hardware and now I need to synchronise DB on them, but only partly - several tables using MySQL Clusters(don't matter which style), each of hardware can act as a node, and we have virtual one as NDB_MGM.
For ex, I have two tables in DB: `users` and `rules`. 
Users should stay unique to each node, but rules should be synced.

**My question is: is it even possible?**

Comment: Hi, @upicik, welcome to DBA stack exchange, would you please provide more information. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is not difficult: Just create the `users` table using a different storage engine than NDB.

> It is possible to create tables using other storage engines (such as
>   InnoDB or MyISAM) on a MySQL server being used with an NDB Cluster,
>   but since these tables do not use NDB, they do not participate in
>   clustering; each such table is strictly local to the individual MySQL
>   server instance on which it is created.

Source: [Appendix A.20 MySQL 5.7 FAQ: NDB Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.7/en/faqs-mysql-cluster.html#qandaitem-A-1-20)